# ZK Binding NotifyChange not work on onChanging Event?

Tags: binding, onchange, zk

I currently use ZK for web-development. Here is my case:

I implement instant search, once text change=> perform search.

**Zul File**

```
    <textbox id="textSearch" sclass="search_text">
                                        <attribute name="onChanging">                                   
                        lbOnChangingSearch.setValue(event.getValue());
                                            vm.onChangingTextSearch();                                  
                                        </attribute>
                                    </textbox>
                                    <label id="lbOnChangingSearch" visible="false"></label>

        <grid id="gridChapter" model="@load(vm.chapterInPage)"> 
          ....
        </grid>
```

**Controller code**

```
ListModelList<ChapterJoinComic> chapterInPage;
public ListModelList<ChapterJoinComic> getChapterInPage() {
    return chapterInPage;
}

@NotifyChange({ "topComics", "chapterInPage"} )
@Command
    public void onChangingTextSearch() {

        FilterObject fo = getFilterObject();
        fo.setSearch_str(lbOnChangingSearch.getValue());

        // 
        doSearch(fo); // Change chapterInPage


       // Manually post Not
 BindUtils.postNotifyChange(null,null,this.chapterInPage,"chapterInPage");  
    }
```

**Problem**
After call onChangingText search, Grid dont update databinding.
But if I continue change text (more call onChangingTextSearch ). The Grid will update, but the updated value is the previous value.

It seems the Grid is a-step slower than my latest Model object.

**Note** If I use onOK instead of onChanging event, the databinding works well.

Anyone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

In addition of Malte his answer.

Textbox only sends data to the server with the `onChange` event to avoid needless network traffic.
If you want to send data to the server with the `onChanging` event, you need to do :

```
<textbox instant="true" />
```

In this case the client will update almost instantly to the server (if you type fast, it will be when you stop typing)

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing stuff up? In my experience, textbox by default sends `onChanging` the way you explain. The JavaDoc on `setInstant` says that it sends `onChange` like that as well, when you set it to `true`.

Comment: I now know what you mean and when you need `instant`: When you use data binding instead of event listeners, you bind against `value`. In order to trigger the `save` binding `onChanging`, you need to then set `instant` to `true`.

Comment: I'm not going to discuss, unless in a chat. It's a easy try and we will see what it does.  Normally you use `onChanging` with `instant` to true, otherwise you need to use the `onChange` event.

Comment: @chillworld thank you for your information about the usage of instant attribute

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `BindUtils.postnotifyChange` when you use `@NotifyChange` already, and you use it wrong anyway: the third parameter should be `this` instead of `this.chapterInPage`. [The JavaDoc](https://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/8.0.0/zk/org/zkoss/bind/BindUtils.html#postNotifyChange(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)) explains that you need to specify the `bean` whose property is changing and the name of the `property`.

Furthermore, replace your `onChanging` attribute with the proper way to call a command:

```
<textbox id="textSearch" sclass="search_text" 
         onChanging="@command('onChangingTextSearch')" />
```

Consult [the documentation](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/MVVM/ViewModel/Commands) for more information on how to use commands. I think because you do not use the command as a command, the `@NotifyChange` is not triggered. And your `postNotifyChange` is wrong, as I said.

Let me know if that works or if there are other problems remaining.

---

**EDIT**

I just re-created an example on my own, and it seems to work. Try it like this:

```
ViewModel --------------------------------

    private String searchText = "";

    @NotifyChange({"chapterInPage", "searchText"})
    @Command
    public void onChangingTextSearch(@BindingParam("text") String searchText)
    {
        this.searchText = searchText;
    }

    public String getSearchText()
    {
        return searchText;
    }

    public ListModelList<String> getChapterInPage()
    {
        return new ListModelList<>(searchText.split(""));
    }

zul --------------------------------------

    <textbox onChanging="@command('onChangingTextSearch', text=event.value)" />

    <label id="lbl" value="@load(model.searchText)" />

    <listbox model="@load(model.chapterInPage)" />
```

Note that I use command binding to call the search method in the model instead of calling it "manually" in an onChanging listener. This way, I actually execute it as a command, which triggers the notifyChange. When you call it like `vm.onChangingTextSearch()` in a listener, the `@NotifyChange` is ignored.

This way, it works as expected, and with every character typed (well, after a couple of millisenconds delay), the list updates. Another advantage is that you do not have to bind your label into the view model, something that zk's documentation discourages.

Can you try to link your zul and model like this and tell me if it works. If it doesn't, you might want to try to create an example on [zkFiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/) that re-produces your code's behavior.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your support. But even I tried replace "this.chapterInPage" by "this", it dont work . The grid dont refresh binding data after these call (@NotifyChange still here)

Comment: I want to note that, on onOK event, the grid refresh well, but onChanging seems do not work, I do not understand why

Comment: @Ronaldinho I have added an example that works for me. Have a look at it and try to change your code to work like this.

Comment: @Harwig: Thank you so much, I copied your code and it works. But in my projects the grid binding refresh still does not work.  I think because I use parent native HTML tag for grid, but your code still work with HTML native tag wrapping